# One invalid QGIS layer makes all layers not to work/be served

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

When there is one layer that is invalid in QGIS project none of the layers are working: I mean if layer A is invalid and layer B is perfectly fine then WMS `GetMap` requests for layer B return 500 server error and in QGIS server logs I can see that B layer request fails because layer A is invalid. How to disable this behaviour of QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

This is supported by setting the environment variable `QGIS_SERVER_IGNORE_BAD_LAYERS` on the server. You can check more details on [QGIS Server documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/config.html).

For example, on my Apache2 configuration I add:

```
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_IGNORE_BAD_LAYERS 1
```

Comment: I have added this line next to other QGIS parameters that are working but nothing changed - one bad layer still makes all layers to fail. Yes, I have restarted `httpd`